# input parametrs for script, count file in dir by extension

Tags: regex, perl, bash, terminal

I'd like to count the amount of the files due to their extension via script in terminal; 
like: 
sm1@smth:~$ ./scriptname.pl pathname extension 
/home/dir/ contains 5 file of *.extention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an equivalent with Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

# countFiles.pl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Glob qw(:glob);

my $directory = $ARGV[0];
my $extension = $ARGV[1];
my @fileList = <$directory/*.$extension>;
my $fileListCount = scalar @fileList;

print STDOUT "$directory contains $fileListCount files of *.$extension\n";
```

Example usage:

```
$ countFiles.pl /Users/alexreynolds/Desktop png
/Users/alexreynolds/Desktop contains 21 files of *.png
```

Comment: That's exactly what i need. But having problem with script:

`ted@NNM:/var/www/cgi-bin$ ./countFiles.pl /home/ted jpg`

`/home/ted contains 0 files of *.jpg`

still there is 1 jpg file.
Tried another folder with png. Still the same result - 0;

Comment: @ted: The quotes need to be removed in this line: `my @fileList = <$directory/*.$extension>;` (otherwise +1) Also, I think `File::Glob` isn't necessary and STDOUT is the default.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Thank you. Works.

Comment: You're right about the quotes, which I removed. However, I would leave in the `use` and `STDOUT` statements, which make the references explicit.

Answer (score 2):

```
find -name "*.pdf" -exec echo -n "1" ";" | wc -c
```

will not fail if filename contains '\n' which isn't illegal. Find visits subdirectories too.

Why do you want to use perl?

Comment: Thanks. To tell the truth that should be done in C or C++. I like Perl more so i was interested can it be done in Perl.
Sorry for my English

Comment: "fail not fail" - which? It seems to me that it will not fail. By the way, you should use `printf` instead of `echo` since some versions of `echo` don't support `-n`. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: You're right - it was a typo. My first version failed with files which contained a newline, and I made a mistake while updating the comment. Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that counts files, optionally by extension:

```
countfiles() {
   command find "${1:-.}" -type f -name "${2:-*}" -print0 | command tr -dc '\0' | command wc -c
   return 0
}

countfiles . "*.txt"
```

Using -print0 ensures that your file count remains correct in case there are file names with embedded newline characters "\n".

Comment: I've never seen the keyword 'command' before. Why is it used? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In shell, use globbing and the `wc` command.

```
ls -d /some/path/*.ext | wc -l
```

Or you can do it in Perl with `glob()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my($path, $ext) = @ARGV;
my @files = glob "$path/*$ext";
printf "Found %d files in %s with extension %s\n", scalar @files, $path, $ext;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopping in late :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

scalar @ARGV == 2 or die "Need two args";

opendir(my $dh, $ARGV[0]);
my @files = grep { /\.$ARGV[1]/ } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

printf "Directory '%s' contains %d files with extension '.%s'\n", $ARGV[0], scalar @files, $ARGV[1];
```

Usage as described:

```
$ ./countfiles.pl <dirname> <extensionminusthedot>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command at console will give you the number of files in DIR directory with EXT extension.

```
ls DIR | grep .*\.EXT$ | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

You can format the message appropriately to match your requirements.

Comment: Have no reputation to vote up. As i've understood it's not possible somehow to set variables for pathname and extension for perl-script via terminal?
Anyway, this works, Thank you.

Comment: I am not a perl user so can't tell how to do it in Perl. But writing a bash script to spit out exact message as desired by you isn't difficult at all.

Comment: Shorter equivalent: `ls DIR/*.EXT | wc -l` (no need for `grep` or `awk`). If you do use `grep`, the asterisk needs to be escaped or quoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls ${DIR}/*.${EXT} \
    | wc -l \
    | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' \
    | awk -v dir=$DIR -v ext=$EXT '{print dir" contains "$0" files of *."ext}'
```

Example usage:

```
$ DIR=/Users/alexreynolds/Desktop
$ EXT=png
$ ls ${DIR}/*.${EXT} | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | awk -v dir=$DIR -v ext=$EXT '{print dir" contains "$0" files of *."ext}'
/Users/alexreynolds/Desktop contains 21 files of *.png
```

Comment: I don't think `wc` outputs any whitespace so `sed` is unnecessary. In any case, the AWK command would take care of it by using `$1` instead of `$0`. You should quote your variables in case the contents contain spaces. `ls "$DIR/"*".$EXT"` and `awk -v "dir=$DIR" ...`

Comment: `wc -l` does return whitespace, which needs filtering with `sed`. At least on the version of `bash` that I use, quoting the variables breaks the `ls` call.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
echo ${DIR}/*.${EXT} | wc -w
```

Comment: fails with blanks in filenames